# Can more 2 dimensional shapes be tessellated in higher dimensions?

Tags: geometry, dimension-theory-analysis

I know only triangles, parallelograms, and hexagons can be tessellated on a plane, but could something like a regular pentagon be tessellated infinitely in 3 dimensions or more?

I think a bit of a harder question, is a shape like this possible to tessellate in any number of dimensions so that every corner is touching the same corner on another instance of the shape, and every edge is touching the same edge on another instance of the shape.  I hope I've been clear enough with what i'm asking

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a tesselation of two-dimensional objects in three or more dimensions?

Comment: As in if you were to cut a shape like lots of pentagons out of paper and arrange them in 3d space in a way that could go on forever, that would be using 3 dimensions.

Comment: When you say "every corner is touching the same corner on another instance of the shape", do you mean that the corner between the 5 cm side and the 6 cm side is touching a corner between the 5 cm side and the 6 cm side on another copy of the figure?

Comment: Yes I did mean that